# How do I filter objects in my function using mongoose?

Tags: node.js, regex, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I only want to pull data unique to a user where my req.user === foundListing.uid.  How can I adjust this function to only show those objects?

```
function show(req, res) {
  db.User.findById(req.user, function (err, user) {
    console.log(req.user)
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    db.Listing.findById(req.params.listingId, function(err, foundListing) {
      console.log(foundListing.uid );
      if(err) { console.log('listingsController.show error', err); }
      res.json(foundListing);
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Why do you select `user` first, and after that `listings`? If `listings` is related to `user` you can create only one request, otherwise this select is unneeded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [find()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-find).

```
function show(req, res) {
  db.User.findById(req.user, function (err, user) {
    console.log(req.user)
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    db.Listing.find({ uid: req.user }, function(err, listings) {
      console.log(listings);
      if(err) { console.log('listingsController.show error', err); }
      res.json(listings);
    });
  })
}
```

I don't know if you can directly use `req.user`. Normally, I use `req.user._id`.

Comment: @KennethVo It worked with just `req.user` too? (I'm assuming `req.user` is an object and not an ID.)

Comment: Yes it worked with `req.user`. Was following a Satellizer tutorial and that's how it was set up so I guess it was actually an object.

Comment: @KennethVo Ah interesting. We both learned something new today. Kindly mark your question as answered.